# Arrays and mergeSort in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, mergesort

```
void Merge(int *array, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    int tArray[20];
    int loBeg = lo;
    int count = lo;
    int hiBeg = mid + 1;
    while (loBeg <= mid && hiBeg <= hi) {
        if (array[loBeg] < array[hiBeg]) {
            tArray[count] = array[loBeg];
            loBeg++;
            count++;
        } else {
            tArray[count] = array[hiBeg];
            hiBeg++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    while (loBeg <= mid) {
        tArray[count++] = array[loBeg++];
    }
    while (hiBeg <= hi) {
        tArray[count++] = array[hiBeg++];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        array[i] = tArray[i];
    }
}

void mergeSort(int *array, int lo, int hi) {
    if (lo < hi) {
        int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
        mergeSort(array, lo, mid);
        mergeSort(array, mid + 1, hi);
        Merge(array, lo, mid, hi);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int array[] = {90, 99, 63, 82, 93, 76, 81, 76};
    //int temp[8];
    mergeSort(array, 0, 7);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My Question is about the nature of arrays during this merge sort code. This code only works if in Merge, O set `tArray[20];` to have that initial value of 20. Why can I not set the initial value to be `hi + 1` which in this case is `8` (same as array)? However, if i uncomment out the `temp[8]` array, and pass that through both `mergeSort` and `Merge`, and use that as `tArray` in `Merge` (with an initial size of `8`), then it works.

I think my lack of understanding is also the reason why my original `merge()` (see below) function does not work either:

```
    //this was my original merge code which does not work.
    void merge(int *array, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        int tempArray[hi + 1];
        int loBeg = lo;
        int hiBeg = mid + 1;
        for (int i = 0; i <= hi; i++) {
            if (hiBeg > hi || (array[loBeg] < array[hiBeg] && loBeg <= mid)) {
                tempArray[i] = array[loBeg++];
            } else {
                tempArray[i] = array[hiBeg++];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= hi; i++) {
            array[i] = tempArray[i];
        }
    }
```

So Basically I am wondering why in the first `Merge()` function, I have to set the `tArray` initial size to be `20` instead of the same size as array, unless I pass along a temp array from `main` (which is initialized to be the same size as array) and then furthermore, why my original `merge()` function does not work, but I think it has to do with my lack of understanding of the first Merge() function.

Comment: What happens when it *doesn't* work. Do you get errors; what are they?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils it prints out a bunch of hex numbers instead of elements of array

Comment: The size of your `tArray` should be something like `hi - lo + 1` rather than simply `hi + 1`. In some case you are going to have `lo = 2` and `hi = 4`, you only want an array of size `3`, not of size `4`.

Comment: @Holt That doesnt work :(

Comment: @crypt3c See my answer, I've pointed out 3 of the "big" mistakes you made, maybe I missed some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code, here are a few of them:

```
void Merge(int *array, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    // The size should be hi - lo + 1, not hi + 1
    int tArray[hi + 1];
    int loBeg = lo;
    // count should start at 0, not lo
    int count = lo;
    int hiBeg = mid + 1;
    while (loBeg <= mid && hiBeg <= hi) {
        if (array[loBeg] < array[hiBeg]) {
            tArray[count] = array[loBeg];
            loBeg++;
            count++;
        } else {
            tArray[count] = array[hiBeg];
            hiBeg++;
            count++;
        }
    }
    while (loBeg <= mid) {
        tArray[count++] = array[loBeg++];
    }
    while (hiBeg <= hi) {
        tArray[count++] = array[hiBeg++];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // it should be array[lo + i], not array[i]
        array[i] = tArray[i];
    }
}
```

Here are some explanations for the 3 mistakes:

1. You don't want an array of size `hi + 1` each time, when you go down the "merging tree", you have to merge array of lower size, so you need to use `hi - lo + 1`. Actually, using `hi + 1` should not be an issue in this case, but you are allocating more memory than you really need.
2. You should not start at `lo` but rather at `0`, or your `tArray[count]` will be out-of-bound. Start at `lo` worked in your case because you were allocating a very big array (of size `20` or `hi + 1`), but it won't work with an array of size `hi - lo + 1`, so you should be careful.
3. Maybe the biggest mistake - You were always replacing the first `count` cell of your original array... No! You want to replace the cell between `lo` and `hi`, not between `0` and `count`.

You need to remember that when you call `Merge (array, lo, mid, hi)`, you want to merge the `array[lo:mid]` and `array[mid+1:hi]` into `array[lo:hi]`.

---

Here are some detailed explanation:

Let's start with the following array `[90, 99, 63, 82, 93, 76, 81, 76]`, at each call to `mergeSort`, you are dividing the array in 2 equal parts:

First time you get `[90, 99, 63, 82]` (`lo = 0`, `hi = 3`), and `[93, 76, 81, 76]` (`lo = 4` and `hi = 7`), and you keep dividing until you have `8` arrays of size `1`. I will write `(array, lo, hi)`, e.g. `([90], 0, 0)` for simplicity.

You should get to a point where you have `([90], 0, 0)`, `([99], 1, 1)`, and so on... You will merge these 2 by 2, so you are (for instance) going to merge `([93], 4, 4)` and `([76], 5, 5)`. When you merge these 2 arrays, you get a call of `Merge` like the following:

```
Merge (array, 4, 4, 5) // mid is (4 + 5) / 2 = 4
```

So, what happens in the `Merge` function?

1. You should have noticed that since you are merging two arrays of size 1 (`[93]` and `[76]`), you need a temporary array of size 2. If you use `tArray[hi + 1]`, you allocate an array of size `hi + 1 = 6`, which is a lot bigger than what you actually need (may not make a big difference here, but imagine if you have an original array of size one billion!). So allocating an array of size `hi - lo + 1 = 5 - 4 + 1 = 2` is sufficient.
2. You are actually is the range `4` to `5` of your initial array, so you want to work on that part, you don't want to erase the part `0` to `1` that you have already sorted! But what happens if you do `array[i] = tArray[i]` in your loop? Well, `i` starts at `0` and goes to `count` (which should be `2` in this case), so you are replacing `array[0]` and `array[1]` instead of `array[4]` and `array[5]`. This can be fixed by doing `array[lo + i]` instead of `array[i]`.

Comment: thanks, I made the changes and it works, but I still dont understand your 1st and 3rd point. Any additional clarification would be great

Comment: If you do not consider my 2 first points and maintains `tArray[hi + 1]` and `count = lo`, it could work if in your final loop you were using `tArray[lo + i]` instead of `tArray[i]`, but it would be very inefficient because you would be allocating an array of size `hi + 1` where you only need `hi - lo + 1`. I will try to add some explnation at the end of my answer.

Comment: @crypt3c I have edited my question to add some explanation, hope these help you... (see my previous comment also, if you did not read it yet).

Comment: I get it now, Thank you so much, I've learned a lot from this

Answer (score 1):

When you create an array like this `int array[20];` you are allocating it in the stack memory of your program. This memory is allocated before the program starts.

Here comes your problem. When you try to do `int array[hi + 1];` you are asking it to allocate amount of memory that is not known before the program starts, and it results in an error.

What you need to do in this case, is use dynamic memory. This memory is allocated and freed on the run. Meaning that you can do `int* array = new int[hi + 1];` and it won't result in an error.

The whole merge function would be:

```
void merge(int *array, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
    int* tempArray = new int[hi + 1];
    int loBeg = lo;
    int hiBeg = mid + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= hi; i++) {
        if (hiBeg > hi || (array[loBeg] < array[hiBeg] && loBeg <= mid)) {
            tempArray[i] = array[loBeg++];
        } else {
            tempArray[i] = array[hiBeg++];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= hi; i++) {
        array[i] = tempArray[i];
    }

    delete[] tempArray;
}
```

I wouldn't advice you to manage the dynamic memory yourself. You should use STL for that: `vector<int> tempArray(hi + 1);` instead of `int* tempArray = new int[hi + 1];`. This way you don't have to have the `delete[] tempArray;` at the end.

Comment: This would result in a compile time error, not a runtime one, and most recent compilers allow for this kind of stuff.

Comment: thanks, I forgot that static arrays cannot be allocated like that

Comment: This does not work either. And even if i statically allocate it to be of size 8 which is the same size as array, that doesnt work. it only works if i make the array size considerably longer like 20 or 50

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort is thinked to work with lists because when you merge 2 lists you can freely attach each element to the element you want.

Example:

```
Merge(List{3,4},List{5,6});
```

results in the following operation

```
List Merge(List a, List b){ //2 instructions even when Lists are long 1000000 elements
    List newlist;
    newlist.head = a.head;
    newlist.tail = b.tail;
    a.tail.next = b.head;
    b.head.prev = a.tail;
    return newList;
}
```

when you have arrays you have actually to allocate a new array of a new size:

```
int * Merge( int array* a, int array* b, unsigned int sizea, unsigned int sizeb){
    //int tArray[20]; // :/ wrong
    int * newarray = new int[sizea+sizeb];

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizea; i++)
        newarray[i]=a[i];

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<sizeb; i++)
        newarray[i+sizea]=a[i];

    delete []a;
    delete []b;
    return newarray;
}
```

This incidentally make the alogrithm much more expensive. Even in the case you have pre-allocated a big enough array the cost of the algorithm is greater because you have to copy all elements at each merge.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but can you tell me why my Merge() function works (the first one in the question) but my merge() (the one at the bottom that I said was my original function) does not work?

Comment: This is true if you want to concatenate your array, here OP wants to *merge* them, so you cannot simply glue the tail of the first list to the head of the second, you need to swap a lot of element in each list.